# Yii2 генерация slug. Таблица транслитерации

Tags: yii2, slug

есть behaviors, который генерит slug

```
public function behaviors()
{
  return [
    [
        'class' => SluggableBehavior::class,
        'attribute' => 'title',
        'slugAttribute' => 'slug',
        'immutable' => false,
        'ensureUnique' => true,
    ],
  ];
}
```

Подскажите, подалуйста, как правильно переопределить таблицу тарнслитерации ?
Спасибо.

Comment: Наследуетесь от класса и переопределяете метод generateSlug

Comment: Добрый день. Спасибо за помощь !

Answer (score 0):

У `SluggableBehavior` есть еще значение `value` которое можно переопределить чтобы оно использовало вашу функцию создания `slug`.

```
public function behaviors()
{
  return [
    [
        'class' => SluggableBehavior::class,
        'attribute' => 'title',
        'slugAttribute' => 'slug',
        'immutable' => false,
        'ensureUnique' => true,
        'value' => function() {
          return возвращаете значение из вашей функции а не стандартной Inflector::slug 
        }
    ],
  ];
}
```

Другой способ - можете наcледовать класс `SluggableBehavior` и надписать функцию `generateSlug`.
Если не ошибаюсь, там нету никакой таблицы и переопределение идет с помощью регулярки. Но это надо глянуть `Inflector::slug`.

Comment: Добрый день. Спасибо за помощь !